# Directly accessing 'List of KeyValuePair(Of String, String)' by Key

Tags: vb.net, key-value

I have a `list` declared as such:

```
Dim list As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String)) = New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String))
```

I'm a newbie to VB, I've searched the web and can't seem to find an answer. Is it possible to directly access a key-value pair using the key ?

Comment: Definitely not VB6, I changed the tag to VB.Net.

Comment: It sounds like you want a `Dictionary(Of String, String)` instead

Comment: Right...with the KeyValuePairs in a **List**, you'd have to search the List for a pair with a matching Key; there wouldn't be a way to access it directly.  As James Thorpe suggests, that is what a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) is for...

Comment: You access the items from a list using the indexer `Item[int]` - not by string value, a `Dictionary` is what you want as has been suggested.

Comment: So if I do use a dictionary declaration as such: `Dim dict As Dictionary(Of String, String) = New Dictionary(Of String, String))`, i can access a value using something like `dict("something")` ? can i update it using the same call ? i.e. `dict("something") = "something else"` ?

Comment: @aidobroschi - yes you can do that.

Comment: is `Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, String)`(x) also a valid declaration ? the declaration from my last comment seems to not work when replacing this(x) with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

1) Change the name *list* to other name like **MyList**, ok?

2) So, assuming your list is named "MyList":

```
For Each kp As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In MyList
     If kp.ToString.Contains(*WhatYouAreSearchingFor*) Then
        Return True
     End If
Next
```